# How do you deal with dynamic resources in a RESTful context?

Tags: rest

From what I understand of REST principles, URLs should represent a single resource, like a user or a product. How do you deal with resources that are random, or generated dynamically?

Suppose I create a resource called api.example.com/integer that returns a random integer. Would I still use GET to retrieve the integer? What would POST, PUT, and DELETE mean in this context?

What about URLs that represent behaviors? Suppose I create a resource called api.example.com/add that returns a sum of two numbers. If I wish to use this resource, do I use GET or POST to submit the numbers to be added?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not required that all resources support all verbs.  That is what the OPTIONS verb is for to find out what verbs are supported.

I would say either of the following are pretty self explanatory

```
GET http://api.example.org/RandomInteger

POST http://api.example.org/RandomNumberMachine
```

Either could be valid.  Just be careful that a GET request may get cached.  If it does then you would not be getting a random result.

One of the main principles behind REST is that you model your urls are representing nouns, not verbs.  So http://api.example.com/add is not an ideal url.

You could do

```
GET http://api.example.org/Summation?Values=2,4
```

or

```
POST http://api.example.org/AddingMachine
```

with some standard format entity body that contains the numbers to add.

On the surface it may seem pretty pedantic differentiating between an url that ends with "Add" and one that ends with "summation".  However, this is a pretty simple example and the REST constraint is there to guide you towards a design that has certain desirable characteristics for distributed systems.

Many years ago people would argue the difference between

```
apple.bite()
```

and

```
bite(apple)
```

was not significant.  I don't think too many would dismiss the distinction these days.

Comment: "One of the main principles behind REST is that you model your urls are representing nouns, not verbs." This is false, REST says nothing about URI naming. I suspect you haven't consulted authoritative sources.

Comment: How about if I rephrase.  One of the easiest ways of guiding you towards accurately using the http verbs is to use Uri's that contain just nouns and no verbs.  There is no requirement to name uri's logically just like in procedural languages there is no requirement to name procedure names with logical names.  However, if your uri can be read as a noun it is more intuitive to understand GET <url> PUT <url> DELETE <url>

Comment: The GET part depends on no caching occurring between server and client, which isn't something you can rely on. You should do a GET on an idempotent resource, which a random number clearly isn't, so I don't think GET is a valid answer. It might work, but it's not correctly "RESTful".

Comment: @occulus  If you set Cache-Control: no-store then you should be able to rely on GET.  It is expected that resource representations vary over time, which is why GET /CurrentWeather is a valid request.  Idempotency does not mean that you get the same weather back on every request it just guarantees that you always get what the current weather is.

Answer (score 3):

I think GET would be appropriate for a random number.  You would simply not allow POST, PUT, or DELETE on that resource.

For the sum, why not just:

getSum?addends=3,5,8

Reponse is 16.

POST [is for when](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) you want "the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line."

In this case, there's no need for the server to permanently accept/remember the addends, so POST is not appropriate.

Comment: It is also for "Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process".  As such it becomes a catch all for anything that does not fit into the other methods. POST does not only mean create.

Comment: I would not consider a few addends a block of data.

Comment: The GET method is for getting a representation of a safe and idempotent resource -- but a random number is dynamic. Using GET for this can lead to lots of problems, surely. POST seems much more appropriate than GET.

Comment: @occulus, GETting a random value is [safe](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) because it will not have "unexpected significance to themselves or others." It *may* update the seed, but this is an expected property of a PRNG, not an "unexpected significance". Idempotent is a bit trickier. Regardless of whether the user does N > 1 or 1 requests, the server may update a seed to a value the user shouldn't rely on; this is a side effect. Repeating the request will change the final seed. Since seed unpredictability is actually a feature, I would lean towards this being idempotent.

Answer (score 3):

A resource is a resource. It can change, mutate, flip upside-down, or anything over its lifetime. Your resource in the first case isn't the random number, but the random number *generator*.

As Darrel said, it's not essential that all given resources support all HTTP's methods to be RESTful. Heck, I've a RESTful system that has various collection resources that allow GET (to fetch the collection), and POST (to append a new resource to the collection and possibly other collections at the same time, which then points to the newly created resource elsewhere), whereas other resources support GET, PUT (for updates), and DELETE. The key thing about a RESTful interface is that it's *universally applicable*--i.e., the protocol's methods can plausibly be applied in a general manner to many different kinds of resource--which is quite *universally used*, which would mean that all resources would need to implement the full interface.

HTTPs methods have well defined semantics. If their semantics apply to your resource in a sane manner, then implement them. If not, don't, or construct a separate resource that does.

In the context of HTTP, GET is a perfectly fine way to do something like your example of summation. Look at any search engine: they all use GET to do search, which is perfectly RESTful. Note though that your browser doesn't have out of band information on how to construct the URL of the resource representing your search, but by downloading a page containing a form, it downloads instructions on how to do it. This is part of the essence of HATEOAS and self description, which you're bound to stumble across as you learn more.

Answer (score -1):

Just use some sort of RPC. REST isn't suited for every purpose.

Comment: Summing numbers is suitable for RPC, not REST.